# How to get data context of a table row when clicking on one of its column, in a reactive table?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a reactive table the data context is passed to the full row, I have to fire an event when one of its columns are clicked and then use the data passed to the row.

```
"click td": function(event, tmpl) {
    //here "this" doesn't give the data,even "tmpl" doesn't have it. 
}
```

Comment: here from **event.target** you will get the reference to the clicked HTML element. You can use that to get the data. Here in meteor I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I bubbled up the event to the row, but all I get is the html elements inside the row.

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: A reactive table row is populated through an object passed to it,I get that object when I fire the event on a row.

Comment: I was wondering, is there any event in javascript which can only be fired through a script but not by pointer or key actions?

Comment: yes of course 
for example if you want to trigger click event of a button, first get it's reference then call the event method like:
`document.getElementById('myBtn').click()`

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor's event handlers, the second argument will be the instance of the template that the event is defined on. From the template instance, you can get the data context. In your situation:

```
Templates.myTableRow.events({
    'click td': function(event, template) {
        console.log("Row data context is:", template.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bubbling the event to the parent "tr", adding a class to it, then firing a click event on the "tr", with you having an event written for the click of the element containing that class.
Inside the click of the tr, you get the full data in "this", you can save the contents of "this" in a reactive dictionary, and the access the reactive dictionary in the click of "td".
After the click of the obtained tr element, you can remove the added class the element, to make it click safe.
you can find a little more detailed explanation here: [Is there any event in javascript which can only be fired through a script and not by pointer or key actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044620/is-there-any-event-in-javascript-which-can-only-be-fired-through-a-script-and-no?noredirect=1#comment59751291_36044620)